# is there group such that has finite maximal subgroup and index of all proper subgroup of $G$ in $G$ be infinite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

give an example of group like $G$ that satisfied  :

- $G$ has finite maximal subgroup
- index of  all proper subgroup of $G$ in $G$   be infinite ($\forall H\lt_{s.g}G);H\neq G $ : [$G:H$]=$\infty$)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Those two conditions seem to contradict each other: the second one means $\,G\,$ is infinite, yet the first condition wants a maximal subgroup which is finite...! If it is finite then its index is infinite and the 2nd condition cannot be fulfilled...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can answer this affirmatively by reference. Wikipedia page on the [Burnside problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_problem) says:

> In 1982 Ol'shanskii was able to strengthen his results to establish existence, for any sufficiently large prime number $p$ (one can take $p > 10^{75}$) of a finitely generated infinite group in which every nontrivial proper subgroup is a cyclic group of order $p$.

Now, in such a group $G$ as Ol'shanskii has constructed, every nontrivial proper subgroup is maximal, finite, and has infinite index. Unfortunately, I don't know Ol'shanskii's construction itself.

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group